# magento controller indexaction method is working only other action method not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, controllers

magento controller indexaction method is working only other action method not working. when i change any method name to indexaction its other action is working.
it irritate me.

http://localhost/magento/test/index {.....this url is working}
http://localhost/magento/test/mamethode{.....this url is not working}

when i replace both method name with each other. In that case also indexaction is only working.

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
     echo 'test index';
   }
   public function mamethodeAction()
   {
     echo 'test mymethod';
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Magento use this pattern: moduleFrontName/controller/action
In your case: test/index/index & test/index/mamethode

Your URL must be:
http://localhost/magento/test/index/index
http://localhost/magento/test/index/mamethode

Comment: thank you brice its working for me. i am too new. and read tutorial i can understand that i am reading tutorial which created for low version of magento.

Answer (score 0):

It should be moduleFrontName/controller/action in your case

http://localhost/magento/test/index will find IndexController and automatically call index action

and for another method it should be

http://localhost/magento/test/index/mamethode